# Flutter Changing Widget's Properties

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget that adding some decoration to out of the widget as the code below.I also wanted to change decoration of the widgets like removing underline in `TextFormField` widget.

```
class FormRowWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget inputWidget;
  FormRowWidget({this.title, this.inputWidget});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var isTextField = inputWidget is TextFormField;
    return Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0,vertical: 8.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  boxShadow: [
                    new BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      blurRadius: 10,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                child: inputWidget// I want to change input widgets' properties.
      ])
  }

}
```

I am using this widget like the code below.

```
children: <Widget>[
   FormRowWidget(
      inputWidget: TextFormField(
       decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
       controller: usernameController,
       validator: (value) {
         if (value.length < 4) return "Username err!";
       },
       onSaved: (value) {
         print(value);
       },
     ),
   ),
   FormRowWidget(
       inputWidget: TextFormField(
       decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
       controller: receiverFirmController,
     ),
   )]
```

The thing I wonder is what is the best way of overriding `inputWidget` in my `FormRowWidget`.
After all, I want to access and change the settings of the widget like the below.Is it possible to handle it?

```
var customTextWidget = inputWidget as TextFormField;
customTextWidget.decoration
```

Comment: I think it's not possible and the only one way is to create custom component that would react depending on the input. I mean there could be some if's, else's inside that.

Comment: I'll propably solve this creating a custom component.thanks anyway.